# tf.global_variable_initializer() with regard to session?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My understandings on Sessions in Tensorflow still seem to be flawed even after reading the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs) and [this](https://jacobbuckman.com/post/tensorflow-the-confusing-parts-1/) tutorial.

In particular, does `tf.global_variable_initializer()` initialize global variables with regard to a particular session, or for all the sessions in the program? Are there ways to "uninitialize" a variable in / during a session?

Can a `tf.variable` be used in multiple sessions? The answer seems to be yes (e.g. the following code), but then are there good cases where we want multiple sessions in a program, instead of a single one?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tensorflow as tf

def main():
    x = tf.constant(0.)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(x))
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In particular, does `tf.global_variable_initializer()` initialize global variables with regard to a particular session, or for all the sessions in the program?**

With regards to a particular session. Check this out.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1,5]))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    first_sess_out = sess.run(x)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    second_sess_out = sess.run(x)

np.testing.assert_array_equal(first_sess_out, second_sess_out)
```

The assertion fails so it is per session.

---

**Are there ways to "uninitialize" a variable in / during a session?**

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1,5]))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    first_init_out = sess.run(x)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    second_init_out = sess.run(x)

np.testing.assert_array_equal(first_init_out, second_init_out)
```

Apparently there is, after running `tf.global_variables_initializer()` the variables got reinitialized. Thus, the assertion fails.

---

**Can a `tf.Variable` be used in multiple sessions? The answer seems to be yes (e.g. the following code), but then are there good cases where we want multiple sessions in a program, instead of a single one?**

Yes, it can be used as you can see on the examples above. Good cases are when you want to execute the graph multiple times in a single run.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed examples. I couldn't construct them myself due to a lack of understandings. But a weird thing: in the first example why does `sess.run(x)` return a `numpy` array in a `tensorflow` session??? Any reference to this quirky behavior?

Comment: When an operation `x` is executed with `sess.run(x)`, the corresponding output is no more a `tf.Tensor`, but a `numpy` array instead.